# what is the replacement for REGEXP_REPLACE(XXXXXX,' ', '') ; in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a code something like this in mysql and i it gives me error when executing in sqlite. Please tell me, what is the alternative command in sqlite?

Comment: From which language are you accessing the SQLite library?

Comment: The code i have mentioned here was used in oracle(No idea of which version). But I need the alternate code to use that in sqlite.

Comment: Found the code in oracle as ReExp_Replace but when i'm executing the query in sqlite it gives the error.